# How to add hook to the_title() and get_the_title()

Tags: hooks, get-the-title

I've having trouble with accented characters now if i do utf8_decode() before echoing the title the problem is solved but instead of changing this all over my theme, can't I do this in one place that upgrade proof? I'm not really familiar with hooks but I think thats they way to do it, havent found out how to do it tho.

Comment: You should rather find out why UTF-8 does not work. That is the default encoding, and it should not be changed.

Comment: Yea true but think is info comes from feed and the accented chars are not correctly in there its there uncoded, which means it gets loaded in uncoded so either I change the importer to decode before storing or i change the enchoing, decoding probly better. Which I just did

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filter for `the_title` functions is this one:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'f711_title_filter' );

function f711_title_filter( $title ) {

    return utf8_decode( $title );

}
```